How to trap an Android crash due to memory consumption
trying to replicate a problem on a customer, I made an Android app (in C# and Visual Studio) that continously allocates memory:
private List<byte[]> _test = new List<byte[]>();
private Timer _timer;

_timer = new Timer(timerCallBack, null, 10000, 3);

private void timerCallBack(object state)
{
  _test.Add(new byte[1000000]);
}


I'm trying to intercept the application closing to dump the system log (logcat), but I did not succeed.
Afert a while, Android (14) seems to kill all existing apps and services, including the UI, that is restarted.
Do you know if there is a way to intercept this kind of system reset to dump system log?
Thank you!
I've tried different approaches, creating a Service inside the same app or inside another app, and trying to override various Service or Activity methods: OnLowMemory, OnTaskRemoved e OnDestroy, Dispose, Finish, FinishAffinity, FinishAndRemoveTask and ReleaseInstance.
But no one of these methods seems to be invoked when Android "crashes", killing all apps and services, and restarting the UI.

Quite often this is really hard/impossible to catch because a lot of Android implementations use Low memory killer daemon
This basically this is "kill -9" or SIGKILL of any processes that it determines it needs to terminate to free up memory.
As the Linux Signal Docs

The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored

There is nothing your process can do about it.
The Low memory killer daemon does log what it kills in Logcat, so you might be able to parse the logcat after the fact to work out your process was killed.

I faced the challenge like this. The case was about video streming C++ sdk which was sprodically starting to consume all the memmory available for the system. The root cause was bug of this sdk for specific Android abi.
I'd say that using Android debugger and crash dumps were told specifically nothing about the root case. Only system logs helped me to find meaninful evidience what was happening on the device.
So my recomendation would be:

Use the exactly the same device as customer do. In my case sdk was properly tested for Linux OS for x86 but was buggy for arm because of float operations.

Use system log for collecting and examining what is happening on the device. I used top command which was helped me to find the app causing the crash. In general case this command might help to gather meaninful insights:
adb shell top -d30 > ./top.txt


I was aware of the app causing the crash but having evidience helped me to point to SDK developers what might be the issue is.

Rid out as much feature/services as you can from the your app and/or device. Pluging application/services/features one by one might help you to find specific root cause of the crash.

